# Using chain rule take the derivative of $x^{\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

How do I use specifically the chain rule for $x^{\sin(x)}$?

Comment: Chain rule only works for derivatives of the form $f(g(x))$.  Where is the $f(x)$?  Where is the $g(x)$?  The $g(x)$ must be **inside** the $f$ for this to work.

Comment: f(x) = x^u g(x) = sin(x)

Comment: You're allowed to post basic questions here! And this mistake is actually pretty common, so don't feel bad.

Comment: What I mean is that the question is just a stupid misapplication. If I was on my guard I would've immediately spotted the problem without making you go through the trouble.

Comment: The version of the chain rule you need for this problem is $$\frac{ {\rm d}~f(g_1(x), g_2(x))}{{\rm d}~x} = \bigg( {\rm D}_1f \bigg)(g_1(x), g_2(x))\cdot g_1'(x) + \bigg( {\rm D}_2f \bigg)(g_1(x), g_2(x))\cdot g_2'(x)$$ where $D_k~f$ means to take the partial derivative of a function $f$ wrt the $k^{\text{th}}$ parameter.

Comment: In your problem, $f(a, b) = a^b$, $g_1(x) = x$, $g_2(x) = \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treating the exponent as a constant, the derivative is $\sin(x)\cdot x^{\sin(x)-1}$, treating the basis as a constant the derivative is $x^{\sin(x)}\cdot\ln(x)\cdot\cos(x)$. Adding both gives the derivative of $x^{\sin(x)}$.  (This is not a coincidence.)

Comment: I think it is better to explain the theorem behind this approach,  namely the multiple variable chain rule. Pointing out a trick without justification does not offer any real help.

Answer (score 3):

The power rule of differentiation
$$
(x^u)'=ux^{u-1}
$$
is only valid for a constant $u\in\mathbb{R}$. It is not valid if $u$ is a function of $x$ itself.

Comment: small note: constants are functions too

Answer (score 1):

In your application of the chain rule you have defined

$$ v(u) = x^u, \quad \text{and} \quad u(x)=\sin(x), $$

and noticed that it follows that

$$ v(u(x)) = x^{\sin(x)}, $$

in order to apply the rule to $v(u(x))$.

The problem is that $v(u)$ as you defined it also depends on $x$, which is the argument of the "inside function", $u(x)$. This invalidates the application of the rule.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. How do I apply chain rule then?

Comment: @mtheorylord This function is not a good candidate for the application of the chain rule.